# how do you authenticate (or pass in the auth file) to ImageAnnotatorClient in Google Cloud Vision (PHP SDK)

Tags: php, google-cloud-vision

I've been able to use `new VisionClient(["keyfilepath"=>'path_to_auth.json'])` and am now trying to use `ImageAnnotatorClient`... none of their example shows how to authenticate for this, and I am not sure where to pass in the authentication file...

Comment: you need to add the the env variable 
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "Your_Json_File_Name.json");

Comment: so there is no longer a way to pass in the authentication keyfilepath on creating a new instance?